# Matlab single digit character

Tags: matlab

Sorry, this might be so silly as a question but I'm stuck in a programme and I want to define that an input argument, in a function I have, is a single digit character. I have tried many things but I ended up with the following code. Single digit character for me is the positive numbers from 0 to 9. It works well when I try to put characters in the command window but it takes integers as well and I want to make it force the participant to put only characters as an input. So the question is how do I force the input to be only a character and display an error when it's not a character?

```
    function toi(x)
    b=char('an');

    if length(x)>=length(b)
            disp ('ERROR the input should be a single digit character')
    end
```

Comment: Do you mean "output" or "input" in the question text? I find your question impossible to understand

Comment: your function does not have an output. `x` is your input. Are you comparing the length of x and b? If you just want to limit `x` to be length of 1, why not say `if length(x)>1`?

Comment: What they have thought me is the following: 
function [a, b]= toi(x) 
where a and b are the inputs and x is the output. That's why I'm referring to the x as an output. Sorry if I'm not clear!  Now what I'm trying to do is that I have a bigger function which looks like this
        function StroopEffect(numberOfItem, typeOfItem)
and they have asked me to make 'typeOfItem' to be a single digit character. The toi(x) is my try to break down the function in order to test it. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes, `a` and `b` are your outputs and `x` is your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~ischar(x)` returns true if `x` is not a char.

`length(x)~=1` or `~isscalar(x)` returns true if `x` is not of length 1, i.e. is not a scalar.

You function:

```
function toi(x)
if ~ischar(x) || ~isscalar(x)
        disp ('ERROR the input should be a single digit character')
end
```

Comment: The reason I put the length there is because I want to force the answer to be a "single" character. So if the length of a character is more or equal to 2 (like '-1' or '10') then it will display an error. I don't know why but although the code Anthony provides should work, it gives me an error even for characters.

Comment: Anthony, I Can't thank you enough! My bad! I tried to test it without my other 'if' statement!!!! Thank you so much for your help! And you've right for the input-output arguments! I made a mistake! The code works!!!

Comment: @AngelaPapazian I'm glad I helped you. Can I ask you to accept my answer?

Comment: I'm really sorry! I am a newbie here and I didn't know how to do it! Was my acceptance successful?? Once again! Thank you a lot for your help and I do apologise for the confusion!

Comment: @AngelaPapazian Hey don't worry too much. You have accepted my answer. Thank you. But be aware that comments are really not for chats like "thank you", "you are welcome" etc. "thank you" could be expressed by upvoting or accepting the answer. So let's stop here :).